# Sage 200, Sql joins - POPOrderReturn table and TransactionHistory table

Tags: sql, sage-erp

I am trying to join `POPOrderReturn` table with `TransactionHistory` table but I cant find an obvsious link between the two.

I am building Purchase Order tracker and wanted to include warehouse **GRN** number once the **PO** in booked in to the warehouse. We store that **GRN** number in `TransactionHistory.SecondReference` field.

Does anyone know how can I connect the 2 tables?

Thanks in advance
Paula

Comment: Can you share your ERD or DDL?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the GRN is stored within the POPReceiptReturn table. This can be connected to the POPOrderReturn table via the Order Return No. in the POPRcptReturnLineArch

Hannah

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you can join the history table to the POPOrderReturn table via the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TransactionHistory  a
INNER JOIN dbo.TransactionType b on a.TransactionTypeID = b.TransactionTypeID and a.TransactionTypeID in (17,18)
INNER JOIN dbo.POPOrderReturn c on a.Reference = c.DocumentNo
```

Please note I have added the transaction type in for reference and on my system, the transaction type of 17 and 18 are 'Purchase Order' and 'Purchase Return' respectively.

You may also want to apply a distinct to this to insure a clean return recordset.

HTH